# How to read in only every second line of file?

Tags: python, file, iterator

I need to read in only every second line of a file (which is very big) so I don't want to use `readlines()`. I'm unsure how to implement the iterator so any suggestions are welcome. One possibility is to call next() twice. Not very appealing.

```
    with open(pth_file, 'rw') as pth:
        pth.next()
        for i,row in enumerate(pth):
            # do stuff with row
            pth.next()
```

Or creating my own iterator like

```
for i, row in enumerate(pth):
    if i...
```

Comment: In fact, you would only call `pth.next` once inside that loop, since the loop itself is also reading one line each time through.

Comment: Ehm, true. In fact I need to read every third line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools

with open(pth_file) as f:
    for line in itertools.islice(f, 1, None, 2):
        # 1: from the second line ([1])
        # None: to the end
        # 2: step

        # Do something with the line
```

Comment: Oh, that looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom iterator:

```
def iterate(pth):
    for i, line in enumerate(pth, 1):
        if not i % 2:
            yield line
```